# Convert a pandas dataframe column with character to the alphabetic order

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to know how to convert a column containing a single character on each row to the integer corresponding to its alphabetic order. From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Any hints on how to solve it?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using `pandas.Series.map` and `enumerate`.

```
import pandas as pd
import string


df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["A", "B", "C"]})
#   col
# 0   A
# 1   B
# 2   C
df.col.map(
    {letter: index for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1)}
)
# 0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
# Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)

print (df)
   col
0    3
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
```

Or if all values are uppercase letter use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(ord) - 64

print (df)
   col
0    3
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
```